# PHP preg_match_all to get PHP code

Tags: preg-match-all, pecl

I have a problem with preg_match_all that maybe you can help.
I have a string with some php code in it. I want to retrieve the code that is between the `<?php ?>` but it does not seem to be working. I am testing the rule with JS and it works properly but in PHP it doesn't.
This is my code, maybe you can spot something I am missing:

```
$contents = "<?php 
  echo 'my test';
?>
<b>This is html text </b>";
echo preg_match_all('/(<\?php).+(\?>)/', $contents, $code);
```

Thanks in advance,
Denis R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$contents = "<?php 
  echo 'my test';
?>
<b>This is html text </b>";
preg_match_all('#(<\s*\?php)(.*?)(\?\s*>)#msi', $contents, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

It may have been that `.` did not match line breaks without the `s` modifier.

Comment: Thank you Aram, that solved my problem. I thought I was going nuts because of this issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$contents = "<?php 
  echo 'my test';
?>
<b>This is html text </b>";
preg_match_all('~(<\?php)(.+)(\?>)~Uis', $contents, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```